# Getting null on list in a One To Many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Spring and need your advice how to get a list of details from products. May I check is this the normal behaviour? What are the ways I can get the list of details? I have tried to call the respective repository but this will end up looping object.

Example:

1. Get all products (findAll)
2. Loop through each products and get the product ID

3. Pass the product ID to Detail (findById) to get the details
   ...

**Product Table**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "pcod")
private int id;

@Column(name = "pnam")
private String name;

@Column(name = "pdes")
private String description;

@Column(name = "price")
private Double price;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public List<Detail> getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(List<Detail> details) {
    this.details = details;
}
```

**Details Table**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Details")
public class Detail {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "limit_id")
private Product product;

@Column(name = "qty")
private int quantity;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}


}
```

**Product Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProductController {
@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

@GetMapping("/products")
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    return productRepository.findAll();
}


}
```

**Json output**

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "King",
  "description": "This is an apple",
  "price": 11,
  "details": null --> Expecting quantity here (e.g. 10, 20)
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Queen",
  "description": "This is an orange",
  "price": 22,
  "details": null    --> Expecting quantity here (e.g. 30, 40)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean looking up Details by product id "will end up looping object"? Do you mean REST json recursion?

Comment: Solved it with @JsonIgnore. Thanks